# Colocar imagem no cabeçalho/rodapé

Tags: html, css

Estou a horas tentando ajustar a posição de uma imagem no rodapé, e após terei que ajustar outra imagem ao cabeçalho, sou novo em html/css e gostaria de pedir ajuda pois preciso criar um site para meu chefe, consegui fazer a imagem descer mas por algum motivo ele não fica parelha a borda de baixo, sempre mantem alguns centímetros de distância e não importa o comando q eu exerça ela não desce...

```
<div id="rodape" align="left">
    <div align="left">
        <h1/>
        <img src="C:\Users\Ricceli\Desktop\tem q ir\Site\css\Imagens/banner.jpg" height="300" width="1350"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#rodape{
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute; top: 1900px; left: -10px; bottom: 0px font-size: x-small;
    width: 150%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2000px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

**Imagem no site:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem sabe como limitar a imagem de background pelas laterais? meu site ficou gigantesco para o lado como podem ver na imagem rs,grato

Comment: Como assim limitar pelas laterais ? evitar que surja um scroll na horizontal ?

Answer (score 2):

O problema da margem que vc não consegue tirar é porque por padrão o `<body>` tem uma margem e vc tem que tirar essa margem "na mão" se quiser que ela não interfira em nada.

Já em relação a imagem, ela precisa tem a largura de 100%, assim ela ocupa apena 100% da largura da tela, se vc usar a medida em PX e ela foi maior que a tela do usuário vai ficar gigante mesmo.

Veja o exemplo como fica

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: plum;
}
#rodape {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#rodape img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover; /* classe pra deixa a imagem com a proporção correta e não ficar achatada */
}
```

```html
<div id="rodape">
    <img src="http://placecage.com/800/400"/> 
</div>
```

**Procure cursos on-line tem várias opções de iniciante a avançado, tudo de graça pesquise no Youtube tb!**